# Not able to reach Flask webserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

This is my test code running on Visual studio 2017, file name is test:

```
from flask import Flask, request      #import main Flask class and request object
from test import app

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/query-example')
def query_example():
    return 'Todo...'

@app.route('/form-example')
def formexample():
    return 'Todo...'

@app.route('/json-example')
def jsonexample():
    return 'Todo...'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000) #run app in debug mode on port 5000
```

But when I run it in Visual studio 2017 and I enter this route "http://127.0.0.1:5000/json-example" in Chrome Browser I always get this error message.

> "404 Not Found"
>   The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

I am a learner, tried following this article:
https://scotch.io/bar-talk/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask

- Python: 3.6
- Flask: 0.12.4
- pip: 18.1

Earlier I used to get the return message with the same code but after updating the flask to 0.12.4, its not working, I think something has changed. I am not able to debug the exact issue.

--Update--

Ok, after updating the flask version to 1.0.2, but still not able to reach the webserver from the url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/json-example. Please check out the screenshot below.

[image]

I get 404 error not found:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Check if you have another service running on localhost:5000? The easy way is to use another port number and check if it works.

Comment: Your code run fine on flask `1.0.2`. You are shadowing `app` imported from `test` (not related to your issue). There is no root, thus `http://127.0.0.1:5000` indeed returns `404`.

Comment: @Philip Tzou There is no other program running on port 5000.

Comment: @jlandercy  I didn't get your answer. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Your code works on higher version. The line `from test import app` is useless since you are shadowing the `app` variable (but it is unlikely related to your problem). Because you have not added route for root `@app.route('/')` the base url `http://127.0.0.1:5000` does return `404` (are you sure you tried the right url?). My advice update your flask version, comment out the second import. Then run and check out the correct url. Also add a root, it is somehow helpful.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, would you mind to share your answer. Thank you

Comment: @jlandercy Not yet solved, I didn't get time to update it, today I checked it by updating the flask version and pip version but still getting 404 error. I will update the screenshot and the output above.

Comment: Please avoid screenshot, they are not helpful. Copy paste instead.

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.run) suggest that you should verify that .env & .flaskenv files are not interfering. (Likely they are not.)

## shadowing

You really need to avoid shadowing one symbol with another.

Please don't name your module `test`, as python ships with a system library with that name. You might use `test1` instead, to avoid the needless possibility of confusion.

Please rename your global variable to `app_`, since your module has an `app.py` file.

## root URL

Please add a `/` slash route, even though it's not strictly necessary.
You will find that it aids debugging.

```
@app_.route('/')
def root():
    return '<h1>top level</h1>'
```

## version

Run a [current version](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/1.0.2/) of flask, please.
It's much better to report problems with current rather than downrev code.

## execution

Rather than having python directly call `app_.run(...)`, please run `flask` instead. Use `export` or `env`, whichever you prefer:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=test1 FLASK_ENV=development
$ env    FLASK_APP=test1 FLASK_ENV=development flask run --port=5000
```

This enables debug mode, which should help you get to the bottom of your routing issues.
Plus, reloading after edits is quite convenient.
The key is that rather than running `python`, you run `flask` which in turn runs `python`.

Answer (score 0):

While I was troubleshooting, I noticed that the above same code works in raspberry Pi zero module with same python and flask version. But it is still not working in visual studio on windows 7. Probably there might be some issue with my visual studio. I will uninstall it reinstall it again. But yes my issue is solved for now. Thanks everyone for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running VS Code on Ubuntu 19.10. The problem was returned string from route view function.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():

    return 'Hello World!'
```

gives error 404. But when I changed to :

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():

    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
```

everything was just fine.